# How to insert a date into mysql database

Tags: mysql, python-3.5

I am trying to insert a data stream including a string value date into a mysql database and experiencing a very strange issue.

I have searched multiple sites for an answer, but I have not found anyone having a similar problem as impossible as that seems.

Using this code, if i try to insert only the date field from the stream into the database, it works with no issues.

```
with open('/home/pi/examples/weather_log.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    linereader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in linereader:
        l_rec_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        data=l_rec_time
        sql="INSERT INTO reports (rec_time) VALUES ('%s',)"
        print(data)
        cursor.execute(sql,(data))
```

However, if I include any other field from the stream (there are 15 others), I get an error.

```
with open('/home/pi/examples/weather_log.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    linereader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in linereader:
        l_rec_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        l_wnddir=int(row[1])
        data=l_rec_time
        sql="INSERT INTO reports (rec_time, wnddir) VALUES ('%s', '%s')"
        print(data)
        cursor.execute(sql,(data))
        db.commit()
```

I have tried the code including the other 15 fields without the date filed and it works with no issues.  If I include the date field I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#157>", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql,(data))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2019-05-24 12:46:05'', '45')' at line 1
```

Can anyone shed light on this?  The error has been making me crazy until I decided to add one field at a time to the code.

Comment: This is the data stream that I am working with: ('2019-5-24 12:46:5', 45, 4.4, 4.6, 45, 1.4, 314, 4.6, 45, 52.6, 72.7, 0.0, 0.0, 100428.75, 4.39, 3.09)

Comment: data is only assigned value of l_rec_time, l_wnddir is never used for anything. Maybe that is causing the issue?

Comment: Sorry, that's a copy/paste error.I assure you, when it IS given a value, the code fails.